# Mvvm Cross navigation: View is called but view model not bound

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I use Mvvm Cross in a WP8.1 Store app. Now I saw that there is a construct to the navigaton problem on the different platforms. So I added this Command in my MainViewModel:

```
public MvxCommand GoToAddMedicineCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<ModifyMedicineViewModel>()); }
    }
```

This will call the ModifyMedicineView properly. But then doesn't bind the ViewModel itself to the view. Therefore all Commands etc. are not working.
I register the View Model this way:

```
CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("ViewModel")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsSingleton();
```

The constructor is executed. At least if I register them as Singleton and not LazySingleton.
The ViewModel inherits from BaseViewModel who inherits from MvxViewModel. This is prepared by the hot tuna starter pack.
The View inherits from: views:MvxWindowsPage as the MainView does.

As far as I understood the conecept Mvc should bind the viewmodel to the view based on the naming.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: As Stuart suggested the I missed the base.OnNavigatedTo.

Thanks
NPadrutt

Comment: Have you followed the steps in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Universal-Windows-App-UI-Project#add-your-view - including `base.OnNavigatedTo` steps?

Comment: Ah, damm. Missed the base.OnNavigatedTo. THX :)